# Center align buttons on header (and make responsive)

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with the alignment of items in a header bar and hope someone can help!

In my header, I have a logo, a tagline, and a button. I also have two social media buttons which I want stacked one on top of the other. I want all of these to align in the center vertically AND to be responsive in doing so - so that regardless of the browser size, these elements all stay in the middle and alignment with each other.

I don't have too much trouble getting the logo/tagline/button to align, but the trouble comes when I am trying to get the two stacked social media icons to align themselves as a pair - I want them to be aligned centrally alongside the Button. My JS edit viewed at full width should give an idea of what I mean... the best I can manage is by using margin settings, which looks fine as long as the browser is full size but as soon as you resize to a smaller width, they start moving out of alignment, so it doesn't really feel responsive to me.

I've searched and tried a ton of solutions, none of which seem to be working too well. I've tried various display settings, using invisible placeholders and wrapper divs, none of which seem to work so far.

So the question is - how can I make all of these header items align vertically regardless of browser size - and keeping the two social icons stacked. I can't help but feel this should be an easy 'aha' moment :-)

A couple of notes -

- The header bar needs to be sticky, and responsive, (so this has caused issues using absolute values)
- The reason I have used buttons (instead of just img) for the Button and Social is because in my full code, I've applied a hover effect using background images/classes.
- As you resize the browser you will see eventually the Button starts to overlap the social media icons - this isn't an issue as I have added a breakpoint in my full code so that before it reaches this min-width it will change around the layout anyway. So my question just relates to how it looks before this break point.

I have put the code on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dskof/xett67qw/

This is by no means my full code - just a simple copy to try and illustrate the part I am having problems with.

Here is the code below as well for convenience:

CSS

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

}

.row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
float: left;
padding: 15px;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

div.sticky {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #008e70; 
}

button {
border: none;
padding: none;
display: block;
margin: auto;
outline: none; 
}

.button {

background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/jPk7tR/button_test.png);
background-color: transparent;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
display: block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
max-width: 100%;
background-position: center center;
min-width: 120px;
}

.facebook {
margin-top: 13%;
background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eqQ7tR/fb_box.png);
background-color: transparent;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: block;
float: right;
clear: both;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.twitter {
background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/cNg2Sm/twitter_box.png);
background-color: transparent;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: block;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: right;
clear: both;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="row sticky">

<div class="col-3">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/hKWQf6/logo_test.png" style="max-width: 100%;">
</div>

<div class="col-6"> 
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/mTzp7m/tagline_test.png" style="max-width: 100%;">
</div>

<div class="col-2"> 
<button class="button"></button>
</div>

<div class="col-1"> 
<button class="facebook"></button>
<button class="twitter"></button>
</div>

</div>

<section>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus malesuada iaculis. Nullam dapibus semper iaculis. In eu magna non lectus tempor scelerisque. Quisque dapibus sed risus a tempor. Nulla sem mi, elementum eget est et, vehicula tristique quam. Vivamus id sapien id justo ornare vulputate in vitae turpis. Nullam leo nulla, aliquam non felis a, lacinia rhoncus nunc. Vivamus eu arcu lectus. In consectetur non ipsum ac lobortis. Praesent finibus est vel enim sollicitudin molestie. Nunc ante mauris, sollicitudin lacinia sem placerat, consequat dignissim leo. Phasellus ac sapien risus. Integer cursus justo sit amet consequat facilisis. Donec a ultricies tellus, sed fringilla tortor. Quisque vehicula quis arcu nec congue.

In varius urna quam, sed congue odio commodo sed. Nullam ut vestibulum     nulla. Sed tempus placerat pellentesque. Suspendisse maximus ut tortor nec ullamcorper. Aliquam vitae nibh in mauris iaculis molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu nisi luctus, tristique nunc eu, fringilla metus. Phasellus gravida ultricies felis ut aliquam. Curabitur hendrerit, diam elementum finibus venenatis, velit elit ultrices arcu, at laoreet diam leo at lorem. Praesent fermentum euismod orci vel tristique. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin euismod nibh sed sem feugiat, nec auctor nisl tristique. Sed molestie metus orci, ac consequat nisl varius a. Duis vel laoreet nibh. Quisque egestas elit eu dolor scelerisque, vel      fringilla quam mollis.

</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance!
Danielle

PS I am new to the forum so hopefully this post is OK - let me know if I have missed anything out!

Comment: Hello, 

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`. Add `display: table; width: 100%;` to your `div.row`, remove the `float: left;` from your `.col` and instead add them `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Yes! This works a dream! Thank you, thank you, thank you!! :-)

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope, your problem will be solve
:)

```
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    //remove float:left
    padding: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **display: table; and display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;**.

- Add display: table; width: 100%; to your div.row,
- Remove the float: left; from your .col
- And instead add them display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

So, You will have something like this:

```
.row {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 15px;
}
```